# In what novel does a girl-turned-vampire discover she also inherited supernatural powers from her father?

Tags: story-identification, vampire

As a teen I read a book about a girl who was friends with a male vampire who then turns her.

They then have to hide her from others on the discovery that she has supernatural powers - I think psychic, or telepathic - passed down from her father's side of the family.

She had a little brother who knew what was going on, and her parents were separated. They went to school together, and the vampire had his own apartment. They run out of hope of finding help in their home town and go out of state to find help from a group of witches.

What book is it?

Comment: Can you remember any of the character names? Or what powers she had? This isn't a lot to go on...

Comment: I want to say a psychic ability maybe telepathic abilities

Comment: It has been some years ago that I read it I remember she had a little brother who knew what was going on and her parentswere separated. They went to school together he (the vampire) had his own apartment. They run out of hope in finding hope in there home town and go out of state to find help from a group of witches.  I hope that helps a little bit more I would love to read the book agent

Comment: It'd also help to know when you were a teenager. That at least tells us the latest it could have been published.

Comment: I was born in 1984. Sorry for the lack of information I appreciate the help

Answer (score 5):

*[Secret Vampire](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/395873.Secret_Vampire)* by L.J.Smith. It's the first of her Night World series.
The girl was dying of pancreatic cancer, and the boy turned her to save her life; though it was illegal in his society.

[image: Book cover]

> The diagnosis for Poppy was death. there was no hope--until James, her best friend and secret love, appeared in the hospital. But this was a James she didn't know. He offered Poppy eternal life. Only he could open the door to the Night World. They're soulmates--but can she follow him into death and beyond?

Comment: Thank you all for your help with finding the book it was a joy to read agen.

Comment: @Theresarockwell Don't forget to *accept* the answer (click the checkmark on the left) to mark this question as solved :-)